# saving data in one transaction and fetching data in another transaction using jpa annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, transactional

I m working on Spring MVC using JPA where m using annotation based structure. I have to upload excel file in data base in which i need to update a column called status using update column method then save data in table then need to fetch all records (updated) from table with status. In this case everything works fine except when i fetch records from database it fetches old data it does not fetch updated records from table. I m using transaction annotation here in method.

I have tried using @transaction(propagation = propagation.required_new) but it also fetches old data.

Any person can suggest me anything?

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public void updateStatus() {
        lotAcceptanceRateRepository.updateStatus();
    }

@Transactional
    @Override
    public void saveList(List<LotAcceptanceRate> lotAcceptanceRateList) {
        lotAcceptanceRateRepository.save(lotAcceptanceRateList);
    }

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Override
    public List<LotAcceptanceRate> getAllRecordsFromTable() {
        return lotAcceptanceRateRepository.OrderByStatusAsc();
    }
```

These all are the methods which i m using to run transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 @Modifying
 @Transactional
```

when you save and update

Comment: In case of update i have tried using but result remains same where as not tried in case of save do you want me to use it in case of save as well?

Comment: if i understand correctly, your save method updates the column with new data, right? then u need to use @Transactional@Modifying there. I had problem. When i had the same problem i even used HQL @Query ("UPDATE User u SET u.password=:p where u.email =:e")  just to make sure it works propely and it did.
And im not sure but is it allowed to save a LIST via hibernate? Have u tried to save each object of your list via foreach?

Comment: Saving data is not problem the problem is when it fetches data it fetches old data even not totally old actually it fetches new row added correctly but updated data is not correct....

Comment: Any solution for this problem. I am facing something similar. Save works but fetch sometimes doesn’t work . Fetch is in different transaction which is just after some milliseconds